# Accessing view id in switch case not working for Android application

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, android-view

Please have a look at this simple code - inside the switch I can't use `clear.getId();` no matter where I declare the `clear` button. In my posted code its been declared in `onCreate`. I know I can write/hardcode the id and it will be ok, but I want to code this the right way.

Code:

```
public class AddProduct extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button sendInfo, clear, cancel;
    EditText name, quantity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_product);
        initializeVars();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            // *** --> case (clear.getid()) : break; // *** This doesnt work
            //  case  R.id.bClear : break;
        }
    }

    public void initializeVars() {
        sendInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAddProduct);
        clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bClear);
        cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCancel);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        quantity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEnterQuantity);
        sendInfo.setOnClickListener(this);
        clear.setOnClickListener(this);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Well `clear.getid()` won't work but I don't see why `clear.getId()` shouldn't (upper case I for `getId()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit messy, but you could extend each of the View classes and add a public int field.  Initialise the field in the View's constructor.

```
public class ButtonWithID extends Button {

    public final int id;

    public MyExtendedView(Context context){
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MyExtendedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyExtendedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defaultStyle){
        super(context, attrs, defaultStyle);
        this.id = this.getId();
    }
```

Then

```
case (clear.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`switch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) requires constant Java Primitives of the type `char`, `byte`, `short` or `int`, or enumerated types and Strings in the `case` statements.  The numeric values that can be auto-boxed to primitives (Character, Byte, Short, and Integer) can also work.

Comment: so there is no prettier way to do this beside writing id ?

Comment: unfortunately no, maybe a set of if statements?

Comment: i try to avoid this mess , i was thinking maybe there is other way . if you say there isnt than we do it the regular way .

thanks for your comment !